# Python - Run multi functions with 1 thread

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I'm new in to Python. I'm trying to do something and I'm not sure if it is possible.
I want to create a Thread that runs 1 function, and after it done run another function.

**For example**

```
thread.start_new_thread( func1 )
//Run this thread only after the first one was finished
thread.start_new_thread( func2 )
```

Is it possible to do it with 1 thread? or i need ot create 2 threads?
What should i do?

Comment: Did you mean: `def func3(): func1();func2()` ?

Comment: I meant creating one instance of thread. And with this instance run two functions, one after the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the same exact thread to run both functions you can just start the thread with func3 that calls func1 and then func2.

```
def func3:
    func1()
    func2()

thread.start_new_thread(func3, ())
```

On the other hand, you can use the "threading" library and start a thread that runs func1, wait until it is finished and then start a thread that runs func2:

```
import threading
t = threading.Thread(target = func1)
t.start()
t.join() # Waits until it is finished
t = threading.Thread(target = func2)
t.start()
```